# Thunderbird not loading any mails from yahoo , POP issue 

Tags: thunderbird, yahoo

I have Thunderbird installed in my Ubuntu 12.04 .previously i have configured that properly and getting and sending message is a usual thing i did , but suddenly from few days i am not getting any mails from it even though there are new mails . I have tried several times by deleting the account and adding again but nothing i got .Previously its worked but now its not . I am not getting the issue . i can add the account successfully but i am unable to get the mails both new and old.

EDIT: In trails i have figured out one thing , with IMAP i can get the mail & i can read them . So now i came to a conclusion there is something with POP .

help me to solve this. 
thank you .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this, but I think that only Yahoo Plus accounts can work with email programs like Thunderbird and Outlook. That's what happened when I tried to set up Outlook, so I switched to Google.

Comment: Hi but i can get the mails if i set with IMAP but i cant with POP. there is the problem .and one more thing with IMAP is , its just listing the mails but when i click them for open they are not loading .

Comment: @GrSr To be honest, I'm not sure. I haven't used Yahoo for such a long time now I don't quite know how setting up Outlook works. But I can tell you one thing -- if something is wrong, it's on Yahoo's end.

Answer (score 0):

First - send yourself a e-mail. It doesn't matter if you send the e-mail to your Yahoo e-mail, it will just return successfully. This would determine if the Yahoo inbox is working fine, sending and receiving emails.

Then test - "get mail" in Thunderbird, and look if that email you send to yourself was received by Thunderbird, and that the email is in the inbox.

Secondly - If that didn't work, look if that email is in the online inbox at Yahoo, and if it is - just make double sure that your settings like the pop3 and smtp is correct. Make also sure that your incoming and outgoing port numbers are correctly - have a look at Yahoo's settings for that...

Thirdly - if that isn't working - double check your offline mode in Thunderbird, you can be offline there, if that isn't the problem. Try using a different email client just to see if it is Thunderbird the problem causing.

Fourthly - if that isn't working, test another email address in Thunderbird if you can, to see if your Yahoo is rejected to Thunderbird, but that shouldn't be a problem. Also have a look at your settings at in your Yahoo online inbox, that you are able to use the account with an email client... I know Gmail you have to go and select in setting to be able to use a email client first, just for security reasons....